# How to update DataGridView after using SetOrdinal() on a column

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataview

I have a DataGridView whose DataSource is bound to a DataView with a table bound to it. If need to be able to insert columns into the table so I just do this:

```
DataView.Table.Columns.Add(newColumn);
DataView.Table.Columns[columnCount-1].SetOrdinal(desiredIndex);
```

Trouble is after doing so the DataGridView reflect the change unless I do something silly like this.

```
DataView.Table = new DataTable("tempTable");
DataView.Table = orginalTable;
```

Wondering how to properly get the DataGridView to see the index change and redraw itself?

Answer (score 0):

`Update()` and `Refresh()` did not work for me.
So I decided to go the following way:

```
var temp = dataGridView1.DataSource;
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = temp;
```